# Python sqlite3 delete not doing anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sql-delete

I am a noob about sqlite (but somewhat experienced as Pythonista), but I am deeply confused why this (Python 2.7, DBPATH is the path to the database)...

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect(DBPATH)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * from jobs"
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fectchall())
query = "DELETE from jobs"
cursor.execute(query)
```

...Outputs the contents of the table (thus the name of the table is right) without altering it. Could someone point out the obvious?

Comment: After the `conn.execute()` toss in a `conn.commit()` to commit your changes.

Comment: The naming is confusing. Defining the cursor as `conn` (connection) is not helpful for understanding. In which case I think @bernie 's answer is actually `connection.commit()` because you're using non-standard naming?

Comment: Sadly the code started as piece of copypasta and evolved from there. I will fix the naming. Thank you all. Edit: Changed the variable to cursor.

Comment: At least as far as I know (and I'm still learning...) `conn = sqlite3.connect(something.db)` and `c = connection.cursor()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual:

commit()

This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this
 method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from
 other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve
 written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Instead, you can set the 'isolation level' when you connect, which automates the commits for you.

```
self.db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name, isolation_level=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `commit()` after every **CUD** operation you do in your database.

> If you **C**reate, **U**pdate or **D**elete, then `commit()`.

Comment: Sorry that I can't select two "right" answers. I think both are very good. Thank you too.